# How to change an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, redux

How to change object using spreads??

```
export const list = [
    {
        id: 0,
        tableName: 'example',
        tasks: [
            {
                task_id: 0, 
                task_short: 'lorem',
                task_full: 'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum',
                time_created: null,
                time_changed: null, 
            },
            {
                task_id: 1, 
                task_short: 'andsf',
                task_full: 'lorem ipsum tes tes est',
                time_created: null,
                time_changed: null, 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

in mine payload comes three properties

```
case 'CHANGE_TASK':
        ///////update, ownId, parentId
```

In **update** I have for example changed **tasks[0]**

And after it I cant solve how to change and return **list**

Comment: sorry, removed the tag by mistake (re-added)

Comment: What do you want to change, and please explain what are `update, ownId, parentId`. and i hope its a reducer and you want to change the state immutably.

Comment: for example I have task in table_list, and I wanna change **task_short** and **tast_full** .   In **ownId** - it's id of the curent changed task, in **parentId** it's id of table where is this task

Comment: http://kanban.antus.pro/ . here is link on my proj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to achieve what you're looking for.

But I can assure that this is not best practice,

Keep your state normalized, do not nest object.

```js
const list = [{
  id: 0,
  tableName: 'example',
  tasks: [{
      task_id: 0,
      task_short: 'lorem',
      task_full: 'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum',
      time_created: null,
      time_changed: null,
    },
    {
      task_id: 1,
      task_short: 'andsf',
      task_full: 'lorem ipsum tes tes est',
      time_created: null,
      time_changed: null,
    }
  ]
}]

const parentId = 0;

const ownId = 1;

const update = {
  task_short: 'Updated andsf',
  task_full: 'Updated lorem ipsum tes tes est',
}

const newList = list.map(item => {
  if (item.id === parentId) {
    return {
      ...item,
      tasks: item.tasks.map(task => {
        if (task.task_id === ownId) {
          return {
            ...task,
            ...update,
          }
        }
        return task;
      })
    }
  }
  return item;
})

console.log(newList)
```

Comment: But what is the best practice??

Comment: check the link [Normalizing State Shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape)

Comment: It exactly what I need, Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it using reducer composition like this:

```js
const list = [{
  id: 0,
  tableName: 'example',
  tasks: [{
      task_id: 0,
      task_short: 'lorem',
      task_full: 'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum',
      time_created: null,
      time_changed: null,
    },
    {
      task_id: 1,
      task_short: 'andsf',
      task_full: 'lorem ipsum tes tes est',
      time_created: null,
      time_changed: null,
    }
  ]
}]

const topReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_TASK":
      return state.map(listReducer(action));
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const listReducer = action => state => {
  if (action.id !== state.id) {
    return state;
  }
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_TASK":
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: state.tasks.map(taskReducer(action))
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const taskReducer = action => state => {
  if (action.task_id !== state.task_id) {
    return state;
  }
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_TASK":
      return { ...state,
        ...action.update
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const action = {
  type: "UPDATE_TASK",
  task_id: 0,
  id: 0,
  update: {
    task_short: 'ipsum',
  }
}

console.log(topReducer(list, action))
```